# Javascript function organization

Tags: javascript, oop, function

I am not exactly sure the differences between saying "function x(){}" or "this.x=function(){}", but I had to make an object oriented JavaScript which is laid out like this:

```
function PROJECT(){
  ...
  ...
  ...
  this.main_call=function(...){ return this.recursive_call(...); }

  this.recursive_call=function(...){
    ...
    var local,variables;
    function helper(...,ref){
      ...
      ref.recursive_call(...);
    }
    ...
    helper(...,this);
    ...
  }
}
x=new PROJECT();
x.main_call(input);
```

My question here is whether this is good style or if there is some way I can call the helper function (which is used to stop duplicating the same code over and over), without passing a "this" pointer. I am a bit concerned because helper function already accesses all the local variables in recursive_call, but it throws errors if I try to access this.recursive_call directly. I also ran into problems with variables overriding when trying to declare this.helper=function(...){...}.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do but you could change your closures. Something like this

```
function PROJECT(){

    this.main_call=function(){
    return recursive_call();
    }

    var local,variables;
    function helper()
    {
    recursive_call();
    }

    function recursive_call(){
    helper();
    }
}
x=new PROJECT();
x.main_call(input);
```

If that doesn't suit what you need to do you could always change your recursive function to be something like this

```
this.recursive_call=function(...){
    ...
    var local,variables;
    var ref = this;
    function helper(...){
      ...
      ref.recursive_call(...);
    }
    ...
    helper(...);
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) from [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/).

1. If `main_call` only wraps `recursive_call`, it isn't needed.
2. For helper functions, consider using function closures when creating the functions so that they aren't created for every call.
3. I personally prefer using `this` in the helper instead of passing `ref`.

   ```
   this.recursive_call=(function(){
     ...
     function helper(...){
       ...
       this.recursive_call(...);
     }
     return function(...)
        ... 
        helper.call(this,...);
        ...
     };
   }).call(this);
   ```

While its a little more complicated, it keeps `this` useful throughout which feels more OO to me. Though you must always ask yourself what objects you need access to, where. If it isn't meaningful having `this` throughout, it isn't useful, don't use it. [Revolution42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267210/revolution42)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265844/javascript-function-organization/2266034#2266034) will suffice.

You might also consider some functional aspects. For example, pass the helper function to `recursive_call`.

Answer (score 0):

To learn about `function name () {}` vs `var name = function () {}` I would suggest reading this related question:

[/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change it into a while/for loop? Recursion is often difficult to read and maintain (which is probably why you feel uneasy about your current code). You can still have a helper() function called by this.helper() but the decision to repeat the process is in the loop logic.